# Why does this work in this bash script's function?

Tags: linux, bash, function, echo, variable-assignment

I saw a function in a tutorial and I think it's pretty cool. It's for coloring text.

Function is defined like so:

```
function print_color(){

  case $1 in
    "green") COLOR='\033[0;32m' ;;
    "red") COLOR='\033[0;31m' ;;
    "*") COLOR='\033[0m' ;;
  esac

  echo -e "${COLOR} $2"
```

Then it's called like so:

```
# Install and configure firewalld
print_color "green" "Installing FirewallD.. "
apt search datadog
```

It'll then colorize the text "Installing FirewallD..".

So the function works only when you precede echoing $2 with ${COLOR}. My question is, how and why does this work this way? Why do I need to echo ${COLOR} so when I echo $2, it's colorized? If I remove the echoing of ${COLOR}, the colorization will not work. I want to know because I seek a deeper understand of BASH.

Thanks.

The script works. I want to know why it works the way it does.

Comment: basically that has nothing specific to do with bash, it's about for all standard output of many languages

Comment: It is not the "standard output of many languages". It is the behaviour of ANSI compliant consoles or terminal emulators. Given the compliance to ANSI, anything outputting those "escape sequences" will trigger coloring, cursor positioning and other effects. Programs or even simple dumping of files.

Comment: The most portable and correct way of doing it would be via https://linux.die.net/man/1/tput and using `printf` instead of `echo -e`

Comment: @Munakas : There is at least some relationship to bash, in that the `-e` option of the bash-builtin `echo` ensures here, that the string `\033` is turned into the ASCII control character _ESC_.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you, all. And @DiegoTorresMilano, why is printf preferred over "echo -e".

Comment: Portability, not all `echo` are the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're called [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). You can use them like this (example code in python for simplicity's sake):

```
red = "\033[0;31m"
no_color = "\033[0m"
print("Something with normal color " + red + "something with red " + no_color + "something with normal color")
```

Which outputs  "something with red" with red and everything else with the default color.

Comment: I would add that the console receiving this strings must have the capability of interpreting and displaying these ANSI sequences.

Comment: @tshiono I feel like I clearly mentioned the fact that the code is in python, isn't it so?

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica I'm kind of busy right now but feel free to edit the answer

Comment: Please forgive my carelessness. You did clearly mention about python. ++ved to compensate the inconvenience. BR.

Comment: No problem at all @tshiono :)

Comment: Thank you, @Munakas. Makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: no problem @synth45 . Not like I care much other ways but could you consider marking the answer as the solution since I want to get 125 reputation to get rid of the 30 min answer cooldown so I could help here on stack owerlfow more

Answer (score 1):

Basically $1 and $2 represents your command line arguments which will become std.input for your script. you can provide as many cmdline arguments as you wish/require for you features. for ex:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if an argument was provided
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
echo "Usage: $0 <name>"
exit 1
fi

# Access the first argument provided
name=$1

# Print a greeting
echo "Hello, $name!"
```

name=$1: This assigns the first argument provided to the variable name.

echo "Hello, $name!": It then prints a greeting message using the provided name.

```
./greet.sh John


 OUTPUT: Hello, John!
```